# Using PSExcel module to edit CSV

Tags: excel, powershell

I currently wrote a powershell script to move the first column down one row and then cut and paste the last value of column one to the very top. Unfortunately the script I wrote was using comObject. I am having trouble converting it to use PSExcel. Would anybody help me?

```
# OPEN CSV
$csv = 'C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx Playground\20180720-Name-Num-Location-0001.csv'
$path = 'C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx Playground\'
$pathdone = 'C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx Playground\done'
$sheetName = "20180720-Name-Num-Location-0001"

# Open the Excel document and pull in the 'Play' worksheet
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$objExcel.Visible = $false
$WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($csv)
$WorkSheet = $WorkBook.sheets.item($sheetName)

# Displays the amount of Rows + Columns
$WorksheetRange = $workSheet.UsedRange
$RowCount = $WorksheetRange.Rows.Count
$ColumnCount = $WorksheetRange.Columns.Count
Write-Host "RowCount:" $RowCount
Write-Host "ColumnCount:" $ColumnCount


# Selects range to cut + Paste, also adds + 1 to total rows.
$range1="A1:A$RowCount"
$range2="A2:A$RowCount"
$rangeadd=1+$RowCount
$range4="A1:A1"
Write-Host "Rangeadd:" $rangeadd
$range5="A$rangeadd:A$rangeadd"
Write-Host "Range5:" $range5


#Selects whole column one, cuts and pastes down one row.
$range = $WorkSheet.Range($range1).Cut()
$rangepaste = $WorkSheet.Range($range2).Select()
$WorkSheet.Paste()

#Selects very last cell in column one, pastes in very first cell.
$range3 = $WorkSheet.Range($range5).Cut()
$rangepaste2 = $WorkSheet.Range("A1:A1").Select()
$WorkSheet.Paste()


# Save and close Workbook
$WorkBook.Save()
$WorkBook.close($true)
$objExcel.Quit()
spps -n excel
```

Comment: When your file is a plain `.csv` I would recomment to use `Import-Csv` and work with the returned object instead of using comObjects or the PSExcel Module.

Comment: @Paxz how would I move the data around properly? via ranges..and everything